# Swapping rows of parity matrix

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

Does swapping rows of a parity check matrix affect the corresponding linear code?

$$
H= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$H^{\prime} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, permuting rows does not effect the linear code, since the rows of the generator matrix generate the code (likewise, the rows of the parity check matrix generate the dual code). The code will be the same, since the order of the generators does not matter.

The dual code is just the orthogonal complement $C^\perp$ of the given code $C$ as a linear vector space. Coding theory has its own terminology here.

The story is different if the columns are permuted. Then the coordinate positions of the code are permuted and the resulting code is permutation equivalent to the original code (and has the same parameters).

Comment: thankyou so it not effect the code? means the code will be the same??  but permuting rows does change the generator matrix isnt it? because $GH^t=0$ so generator is different then the code will be different too? its is this related to the error pattern also(?) is this related to hamming parity too? i still dont quite understand relation of H and G and linear code

Comment: thankyou but what do you mean by dual code? is there relation to error pattern too(?)

Comment: thankyou so much! so changing row in geenrator or parity matrix does not effect the code, but changing column in parity or generator will effect the original code?

Comment: thankyou but is this also because, in generator matrix,  row order doesnt matter as long as the row are linear independent to each other? but still produce the same code result?

Comment: In a generator matrix, the rows are linearly independent by definition. But even if the rows of a matrix are not linearly independent, the ordering does not matter. The basis of a space is a set and one a set there is a priori no ordering of the elements.

Comment: ok thankyou so much!! so it will produce $2^k$ code nomatter what is generator matrix and parity matrix(?)

Comment: The same code is provided if the $k\times n$ generator matrix is multiplied by a non-singular $k\times k$ matrix (i.e., determinant nonzero) from the left.

Comment: ok thankyou so much!!